# Integer to character count for simple graph?

Tags: mysql

Is there an expression I can use to convert integers to a count of characters, for simple graphing?

What I want is this:

```
+---+-------+
| 5 | ----- |
| 1 | -     |
| 2 | --    |
| 4 | ----  |
+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT REPEAT('-',int_column) FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

From the manual

```
mysql> SELECT REPEAT('MySQL', 3);

'MySQLMySQLMySQL'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_repeat    ->

Comment: Like KAD said tie it into a column and yourTable and you're set to go